# Use a method from another class

Tags: java

I was given a class called `PokerHand` that creates a poker hand.

Now I want to use the same methods on a different class called `fiveCardDraw` to create a totally different poker hand for a dealer and a player so I created two arrays:

```
PokerHand [] dealer = new PokerHand[5];
PokerHand [] player = new PokerHand[5];
```

Where I am going to store the cards, but I want to use the methods on the `Pokerhand` class such as:

```
addCard()
getCards()
```

How can I called those methods into the `fiveCardDraw` class and store them into the arrays I created?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this PokerHand [] dealer = new PokerHand[5];? What you are creating is not a PokerHand of 5 cards, but an array that will be capable of storing up to 5 poker hands. Is that your intetion?

Answer (score 0):

You can either call them from the objects that are of type `PokerHand` (my recommended method)

```
dealer[i].addCard();
player[i].getCards();
```

Or if they're applicable you can convert the methods to `static` and they'll be callable from `PokerHand.addCard()`.

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.foo = PokerHand.addCard();
```

Answer (score 0):

if they are static methods then you would put:

```
fiveCardDraw.addCard();
```

if they are not static then you would have to create and instance (or object) of the fiveCardDraw class ex:

```
fiveCardDraw cardDraw = new fiveCardDraw();
```

and then add

```
cardDraw.addCard();
```

Answer (score -1):

what do you want is this?`

```
class fiveCardDraw {
private PokerHand [] player = new PokerHand[5];
private PokerHand [] dealer = new PokerHand[5]; 
pulic void addPlayerCard(PokerHand [] ph){
do something...
} 
pulic void addDealerCard(PokerHand [] ph){
do something...
} 
public PokerHand [] getPlayerCards()
return player;
}
public PokerHand [] getDealerCards()
return dealer;
}
```

`